# ERR_IMPORT_ASSERTION_TYPE_MISSING for import of json file

Tags: javascript, typescript

This code was working fine.

I don't know if it's because I upgraded to Node 17 or what, but now I get

```
TypeError [ERR_IMPORT_ASSERTION_TYPE_MISSING]:
  Module "file:///Users/xxxxx/code/projects/xxxxx/dist/server/data/countries.json" 
  needs an import assertion of type "json"
```

In my `api.ts` I have:

```
import countryTable from './data/countries.json';
```

Here's how I start `api.ts` which is used by `server.ts`:

```
NODE_ENV=production node --optimize_for_size --trace-warnings --experimental-json-modules --no-warnings server/server.js
```

Answer (score 320, accepted):

Update: According to the proposal, the new keyword is `with` instead of `assert`, but `assert` is supposed to stay for compatibility reasons. The new code would look as follows:

```
import countryTable from "./data/countries.json" with { type: "json" };
```

---

You will need to use:

```
import countryTable from "./data/countries.json" assert { type: "json" };
```

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-import-assertions

Comment: Import assertions were introduced in node v17.1.0 according to [this](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#err_import_assertion_type_missing), but became required after v17.5.0 (related to this change:https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/40785). Import assertions address a security concern (https://v8.dev/features/import-assertions) about trusting cross-origin imports.

Comment: Thanks! You just saved me a world of trouble understanding why a code that worked fine yesterday suddenly stopped working! I actually needed the second version detailed in GitHub, but you saved me a world of hurt!

Comment: i dont have a data folder

Comment: @PhilipRego this is just the file used in the original question. You only have to add the `assert {type: "json"}` part.

Comment: If you do this and get `TS2821: Import assertions are only supported when the '--module' option is set to 'esnext'` you can just add `// @ts-ignore` to the line above the import as a workaround for the moment.

Comment: Thankyou @Malvineous! The 'esnext' thing had been killing me!

Comment: I had to dive deep to find this answer. The language the most used in the world when python has no problem to do this and much more around imports. require had no problem to do this. Few hours lost.

Comment: @UneconscienceUneSource its a CORS related security measure. Obviously python does not have to deal with this.

Comment: In the link: `Motivation` .. LOL type lots of stuff and make life difficult.

Comment: what about dynamic imports? like `import("./package.json")`

Comment: found it. for dynamic import use `import("./some.json", { assert: { type: "json" }})`

Comment: Import assertions are deprecated and will be removed from the language, to be replaced with https://github.com/tc39/proposal-import-attributes, that leaves node in the situation where there is no future-proof way to import JSON, only other engines like bun offer that.

Comment: @silverwind import attributes are basically the same but they just renamed it and changed the syntax. And I don't really see  why that would stop Node from implementing it?

Edit: Also, as I said weeks ago in the edit of the answer, assert is meant to stay supported to not break compatibility.

Comment: with is a syntax error in Node 18: `Original error stack trace: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'with'`. So should continue to use the assert form

Comment: the `assert` form gives the following warning: `(node:139213) ExperimentalWarning: Import assertions are not a stable feature of the JavaScript language. Avoid relying on their current behavior and syntax as those might change in a future version of Node.js.`

Answer (score 30):

For anyone having ESLint validation issues (due to `assert` not being supported yet), you can try loading the JSON from the filesystem synchronously:

```js
const loadJSON = (path) => JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(new URL(path, import.meta.url)));

const countries = loadJSON('./data/countries.json');
```

Reference: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/discussions/15305

Comment: readFile blocks, so it would be better to  promisify it and use top level await

Comment: I get `Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module`

Comment: @coler-j this will not work with CJS.

Answer (score 18):

To import `.json` in ES modules you can use

```
module.createRequire()
```

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/esm.html#no-require-exports-or-moduleexports

[because assertions are still experimental in v18.12.1 of node.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OYEV.png)

```
import { createRequire } from 'node:module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);

const countryTable = require('./data/countries.json');
```

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/module.html#modulecreaterequirefilename

Answer (score 7):

If you are **not** using `Node v17.1.0+` and are instead stuck with v16 or lower, AND you are using the `--es-module-specifier-resolution=node` flag to the node process, something like this:

```
{
  "start": "node --es-module-specifier-resolution=node --no-warnings src/index.js"
}
```

trying to do something like this:

```
import swaggerDocument from "../swagger.json" assert { type: "json" }
```

will result in the following error:

> ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use
> import instead.

Trying to do this:

```
const swaggerDoc = require('../swagger.json');
```

will result in the same above error.

There are several solutions:

```
import { readFile } from 'fs/promises';
const swaggerDoc = JSON.parse(
  await readFile(new URL('../swagger.json', import.meta.url))
);
```

or:

```
import { createRequire } from "module";
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
const swaggerDoc = require("../swagger.json");
```

I prefer the first way. I think it is a little more clear as to what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

This works only if you need to import a specific object that having issues with ES6+.

```js
module.createRequire()
```

**Code Example:**

```js
import { createRequire } from 'node:module'

// Import the package.json file to get the version number by using the createRequire function
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url)
const { version } = require('../../package.json')
```

You can also use a bundler to convert your code on commonjs.

Answer (score -1):

once you have imported your data,and signifying the address , you should type assert {type:"json"} to eliminate this error. import assertion has been introduced in node v17 for data checking and authentication.

Type something like this
import data from './data/mock.json' assert {type:"json"}