# React not rendering JSON

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, json

I have the following codes that was supposed to render data from a json file. It doesn't display me anything, except the h1 with the curly braces, instead of the data wanted. here is the code:

```
import prod from "../../data/produtos.json";

export default function Produto(props) {
  return (
    <figure>
      <img src={prod.imagem}></img>
      <figcaption>(prod.titulo)</figcaption>
      <p>(prod.preco)</p>
      <button className="btn"> Adicionar ao carrinho </button>
    </figure>
  );
}
```

```
import "./Produtos.css"
import productions from "../data/produtos.json";
import Produto from "./Produto";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Produtos(props) {
  const [lista, setLista] = useState(productions);
  return (
    <div className="produtos">
      {lista.map((product) => (
        <div className="Products">
          <Produto id={product.id} {...product} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "titulo": "",
    "preco": 16.9,
    "imagem": "../public/imagens/pwero.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "titulo": "",
    "preco": 26.89,
    "imagem": "../public/imagens/oepw.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "titulo": "",
    "preco": 17.4,
    "imagem": "../public/imagens/ewer.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "titulo": "",
    "preco": 2.2,
    "imagem": "/////w"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "titulo": "",
    "preco": 49.99,
    "imagem": ""
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "titulo": "",
    "preco": 5.99,
    "imagem": "zzzzys"
  }
]
=
```

it should be rendering the json data. I don't know if the problem is in the map. The json file is imported right in both components.

Comment: Importing JSON depends on which version of Node you're using. Have you seen an [ERR_IMPORT_ASSERTION_TYPE_MISSING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70106880/err-import-assertion-type-missing-for-import-of-json-file) error in the console?

Answer (score 1):

In `Produto`, you need to access `props` (not `prod`) and use curly brackets `{}`. You should not be importing/loading any JSON at this point.

```
export default function Produto(props) {
  return (
    <figure>
      <img src={props.imagem} alt={props.titulo}></img>
      <figcaption>{props.titulo}</figcaption>
      <p>{props.preco}</p>
      <button className="btn"> Adicionar ao carrinho </button>
    </figure>
  );
}
```

I would initialize the `lista` state with an empty array and use an effect to either fetch it (recommended), or load it from the JSON file. Also, if you use `Array.prototype.map`, you should supply a `key` prop.

```
import "./Produtos.css"
import productions from "../data/produtos.json";
import Produto from "./Produto";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Produtos() {
  const [lista, setLista] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLista(productions);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="produtos">
      {lista.map((product) => (
        <Produto key={product.id} id={product.id} {...product} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You could alternatively load the JSON asynchronously.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    const response = await fetch("../data/produtos.json");
    const produtos = await response.json();
    setLista(produtos);
  })();
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding a `return` statement in the map.

Here is the snippet for the code :

```
import "./Produtos.css"
import productions from "../data/produtos.json";
import Produto from "./Produto";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Produtos(props) {
  const [lista, setLista] = useState(productions);
  return (
    <div className="produtos">
      {lista.map((product) => {
       return (
        <div className="Products">
          <Produto id={product.id} {...product} />
        </div>
       )})}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: That does not matter, since the OP used an arrow function with a single expression.

Answer (score 0):

1- You don't need to import the data into your **Produto** component. Its code should be :

```html
export default function Produto({ prod }) {
    return(
        <figure>
            <img src={prod.imagem}></img>
            <figcaption>{ prod.titulo }</figcaption>
            <p>{ prod.preco }</p>
            <button className='btn'> Adicionar ao carrinho </button>
            
        </figure>
    )
}
```

Instead of putting the js instructions in `parentheses ()`, you must instead put them in `braces {}`

2- As far as the `Produtos` component is concerned, all you have to do is pass the product as an attribute of the Produto component

```html
import productions from '../data/produtos.json'
import Produto from "./Produto"
import { useState } from "react";
export default function Produtos(props){
    
    const [lista, setLista] = useState(productions);
    return(
        <div className="produtos">
            {lista.map(product => (
                  <div className="Products">
                    <Produto id={product.id}  prod={product}/>
                  </div>
                ))}            
        </div>
 )
    }
```

Comment: You can spread props into a component.